# Find value of $b$ and $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

Suppose $x^{12} - 1$ is divisible by $x^4 + bx^2 + c$ . Find all possible values for $b$ and $c$ . I've tried to use $x^4 + bx^2 + c = 0$ for finding remainder and equaling it with zero but didn't help for finding $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Note that $x^{12}-1$ is a difference of cubes and also a difference of squares.  Are $b$ and $c$ supposed to be real?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes , $b$ and $c$ are real numbers .

Comment: Setting $x^2=u$ might simplify the algebra..

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Cracking good comment.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you Mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^{12}-1=(x^6-1)(x^6+1)=(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)=(x^4-1)(x^4+x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$$
The situation is a bit trickier since those $3$ don't need to be the only possible solutions. Using the substitution suggested in comments by MathematicianByMistake $t=x^2$ we get $t^6-1=(t^3-1)(t^3+1)=(t-1)(t+1)(t^2+t+1)(t^2-t+1)$ needs to be divisible by $t^2+bt+c$, since $t^2-t+1$ and $t^2+t+1$ are irreducible you're left with $(t-1)(t+1)$ which can be combined only in one way to get $t^2-1$ hence those are the only $3$ choices.

Comment: This shows three such factors, but how do we know that they are the only ones? I can pair twelfth roots of unity as complex conjugates to get quadratic factors with real coefficients. How do we show that these cannot be combined in other ways to give factors of the form suggested?

Comment: @MarkBennet I was looking for a answer using remainder theorem . I think it can solve the problem which you said .

Comment: @S.H.W MathematicianByMistake's comment on the question will do most of the work for you.

Comment: @MarkBennet You're right, I thought in general that the expansion is unique (which I know realize isn't true).

Comment: You still got to the heart of the question and made real progress. +1 well deserved.

Comment: Good work +1, thanks for the mention:)